# How to add both "EXIST" and "IN" validation in Laravel for single input

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

Please check below my validation rule. But it's not working. I am sharing database table screen shot and error which getting.

```
'section.2.model_of_vehicle'  => 'required|exists:vehicles,model_name|in:Ford Transit, Ford Tourneo, Volkswagen Crafter, Mercedes Sprinter, Toyota Prius Hybrid, Volkswagen Caddy Maxi, Renault Master, Peugeot Boxer, Vauxhall Vivaro, Vauxhall Movano, Other',
```

[image: Image for values which I have in database table]

[image: Image for values I am putting in form]

[image: Image for error which I am getting]

Comment: If all the values exist already on your table in DB, why would you add the "in" validation? I think exists already is sufficient, unless theres something else behind that?

Comment: @MarwaneEzzaze Yes but I need to validate some values not from table. I have code which covert this select into input text.